# Novice plotting coordinates on map in R with csv file

Tags: r, google-maps, csv, ggplot2, ggmap

I am new to r and have been trying for hours to plot points of a family of butterflies on a map of arizona.  I could be doing totally wrong or have something missing im not sure and any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have the following codes now and have tried many others:

```
rio = read.csv("Rioninidae_Cleaned.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
arizona <- get_googlemap(center=c(lon=-110.713,lat=31.815), zoom = 3)
lon <-data.frame(rio$latitude)
lat <-data.frame(rio$longitude)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(lon,lat))
df
arizona <- get_googlemap(center = c(lon = -110.713,lat = 31.815), zoom = 3)
ggmap(arizona) +
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = lon, y = lat), size = 5, shape = 21) +
  guides(fill = FALSE, alpha = FALSE, size = FALSE)
```

my csv file can be found at:   https://www.dropbox.com/s/yxj1uvmt9bw8gvn/Rioninidae_Cleaned.csv?dl=0

```
       genus province         county latitude longitude
1   Apodemia  Arizona         Apache 33.90011 -109.5844
2   Apodemia  Arizona Cochise County 31.46260 -110.2895
3   Apodemia  Arizona Cochise County 31.46260 -110.2895
4   Apodemia  Arizona    Santa Cruz  31.50503 -110.6547
5     Emesis  Arizona     Santa Cruz 31.74001 -110.9411
6     Emesis  Arizona     Santa Cruz 31.74001 -110.9411
7     Emesis  Arizona     Santa Cruz 31.38333 -111.0833
8   Apodemia  Arizona     Santa Cruz 31.38333 -111.0833
9 Calephelis  Arizona           Pima 31.76667 -111.5500
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you are probably looking for something like this.

```
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)

# Get a map
arizona <- get_map(location = c(lon = -110.713, lat = 31.815), zoom = 6)

ggmap(arizona) +
geom_point(data = mydf, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, fill = genus), size = 3, shape = 21)
```

[image]

DATA

```
mydf <- structure(list(genus = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("Apodemia", "Calephelis", "Emesis"), class = "factor"), 
province = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = "Arizona", class = "factor"), county = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("Apache", "Cochise County", 
"Pima", "Santa Cruz", "Santa Cruz "), class = "factor"), 
latitude = c(33.9001056, 31.4625978, 31.4625978, 31.5050272, 
31.7400056, 31.7400056, 31.38333333, 31.38333333, 31.76666667
), longitude = c(-109.58444, -110.2895241, -110.2895241, 
-110.65472, -110.94111, -110.94111, -111.0833333, -111.0833333, 
-111.55)), .Names = c("genus", "province", "county", "latitude", 
"longitude"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly it! Thank you very much, I would have never figured out that structure command!

Comment: @poolshark Pleasure. Glad to hear this is what you are after. :)

Comment: Thanks! Just wondering what would i do if i had over a 100 coordinates for a family? How would i change the structure?

Comment: @poolshark Not sure what you mean. But, say if you have 100 data points for one type of genus, you do not have to do anything. All you have to do is to add the data points to your data frame.

Comment: Well I have this csv: https://www.dropbox.com/s/akwecz1xb35ls7f/Carabidae_Cleaned.csv?dl=0  and I want to overlay its' coordinates on the map as well, would I just type in the coordniates in to the data frame? Sorry I am a complete noob on this

Comment: @poolshark Seeing how you wrote your code, I think you are confused about how to import your data and create a data frame. `mydf <- read.csv("Carabidae_Cleaned.csv", header = TRUE)` will import your data and you have a data frame. That's all you have to do. Once you have the data imported, run the code from my answer and see what happens. I believe you have a map you want.

Comment: Ah it works wonderfully, I understand now thank you so much! I was confused on thinking I would physically have to type in the coordinates in structure. You are a life saver! :)

Comment: @poolshark All good. I am glad that you now have a clear idea of what you are doing. :)